# Bootstrap modal using custom CSS (from HTML template) not working well

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal that on a Button click I show it.

Everything works great but the Modal is displayed in the very right of the screen that I can't see even the Modal footer buttons.

I'm using a HTML Template that has a custom Bootstrap CSS and that's the reason of the issue.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

My Modal html code is:

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery code is:

```
   $('#btnSave').click(function() {
                $('#myModal').modal('show')
            });
```

> Here is the jsFiddle using the custom CSS that I have (from the HTML Template).

http://jsfiddle.net/uuvgLnsx/1/

Comment: This is a CSS issue post your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    left: 50%;
    right: auto;
    width: 600px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
```

The 'left: 50%' pushes the your dialog box into the middle.  Change left to auto.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="position: fixed; left: 25%; width:60%;>
```